# Should I inform a company if the application page on their website has style bugs?

Tags: job-search

I recently applied for a job on a company's website. On the application page, there were a few style issues that were clearly bugs, such as the logo doubling in size and obscuring the page when scrolling down.

If I am communicating with an internal employee during my application process, should I let them know? I'd like to help out, but I don't want to appear condescending if its going to hurt my chances in the application.

Comment: no. Unless you are being hired for a website designer role

Comment: Would you inform an interviewer that their belt doesn't match their shoes? In the context of applying to/interviewing for a position, this isn't the right context to mention such issues... unless you're specifically interviewing for a position responsible for managing and maintaining the company website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> should I let them know?

I would not. You can wait till the interview is over. Irrespective of whether you end up joining them or not, it is easier if you mention this later.